# SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module on gnome shell extension

Tags: javascript, gnome-shell-extensions

The settings of extension CoverflowAltTab@palatis.blogspot.com had an error:

```
SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

Stack trace:

```
@file:///home/rudra/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/CoverflowAltTab@palatis.blogspot.com/prefs.js:28:16
_init/GLib.MainLoop.prototype.runAsync/</<@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/GLib.js:266:34
```

The code starts with (ignoring the comments for the first 25 lines)

```
const { Adw, Gdk, GLib, Gtk, Gio, GObject} = imports.gi;

const Config = imports.misc.config;  #This is line no: 28.

const Gettext = imports.gettext.domain('coverflow');
const _ = Gettext.gettext;

const Me = imports.misc.extensionUtils.getCurrentExtension();
const UIFolderPath = Me.dir.get_child('ui').get_path();
const ExtensionImports = Me.imports;
const Lib = ExtensionImports.lib;

const SCHEMA = "org.gnome.shell.extensions.coverflowalttab";
```

I have no knowledge on javascript. Can someone kindly let me know how to correct this error?

Comment: There's no export statement in your code?

Comment: no. `grep export *.js` returns nothing.

Comment: That wouldn't capture files in directories, you didn't add the recursive flag. Or are all your files in a single directory? What's misc.config?

Comment: There is no match either, with `grep -r`. `imports` must be some library.

Comment: I would presume it's a binding created by the gnome-shell host environment, especially looking at some of the namespaces

Answer (score 4):

It looks a lot like you're trying to use an extension from <= GNOME 44, on (a pre-release of) GNOME 45.

As of GNOME 45, GNOME Shell and extensions have migrated to ESModules. There is more information in the official blog post, [Extensions in GNOME 45](https://blogs.gnome.org/shell-dev/2023/09/02/extensions-in-gnome-45/). If you're looking to port this extension, there is a guide to [Port Extensions to GNOME Shell 45](https://gjs.guide/extensions/upgrading/gnome-shell-45.html).